# message headers won't build first

Tags: ros, custom-message, message, generate-messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using ROS hydro and indigo for the past year, and I can't get my custom message files to build in the correct order. Whenever I move my packages to a new computer and do a fresh build, I get errors about missing message header files. I am usually able to get everything to build if I remove the executables from my  CMakeLists and only build the message files first, but this is cumbersome since I have 8 or 9 custom packages.

Is there something I can do to my CMakeLists to fix this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188982/message-headers-won%27t-build-first/) by [Ralff](https://answers.ros.org/users/11841/ralff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As McMudro said you are missing some dependencies. To make it bit clearer:

catkin creates several files which are used as flags to determine if something has been built or not. The flags for messages are always following the same naming convention:

```
package_name_generate_messages_cpp
```

Where 'package_name' is of course the name of your package and '_generate_messages_cpp' is a fixed name for the build flag and cannot be changed. One of the problems is that if you misspell it, catkin will not complain but it also does not have any effect. Therefore you have to make sure that you always spell it right.

One example would be:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_package)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS genmsg roscpp std_msgs geometry_msgs ... message_generation)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
add_message_files(
  FILES
  MyMessage.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs 
  ...
  geometry_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
# LIBRARIES strands_gazing
  CATKIN_DEPENDS std_msgs geometry_msgs ...
# DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
add_dependencies(foo my_package_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(foo
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Where the important line is this one `add_dependencies(foo my_package_generate_messages_cpp)` which makes sure that the flag `my_package_generate_messages_cpp` exists before trying to build `foo`. Therefore it makes sure that the message headers are generated before building the binary.

Now, what if you have custom messages in other packages on which this package relies and which therefore have to be build first? You could include them in the same way in the add_dependency line but it is much more convenient to use one of catkins makros for this: `${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}` which contains all the `_generate_messages_cpp` flags for all the catkin packages you listed in the `find_package` line. So all you have to change is:

- Add your second package to the `find_package` statement of the first one: `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS my_other_package genmsg roscpp geometry_msgs ... message_generation)`
- Add the macro to the dependencies `add_dependencies(foo my_package_generate_messages_cpp ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})`

In fact it can never hurt to include this macro.

Another very common source of error is including the `my_other_package_generate_messages_cpp` flag in the dependencies of `my_package` (e.g. by using the catkin macro described above) and forgetting to add it in the package.xml file. If you do not add `my_other_package` as a build and run dependency to the package.xml of `my_package`, catkin will assume that both packages try to build the messages in `my_other_package` and since you cannot have the same type of message twice it will exit with a cmake error. So in this case your package.xml file would have to look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
 <name>my_package</name>
 ...

 <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

 <build_depend>my_other_package</build_depend>
 <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
 <build_depend>genmsgs</build_depend>
 <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
 <build_depend>std_msgs_msgs</build_depend>
 ...
 <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>

 <run_depend>my_other_package</run_depend>
 <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
 <run_depend>genmsgs</run_depend>
 <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
 <run_depend>std_msgs_msgs</run_depend>
 ...
 <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>

 <export/>
</package>
```

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 41

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ralff](https://answers.ros.org/users/11841/ralff/) on 2014-08-06**:
Thanks. The problem was that I didn't add the dependencies for the message files from other packages for generating the messages. I only had the dependencies for the package itself.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-09-03**:
Hi Chrissi, maay I know where did you find those informations?
I ve read lolts of tutorials about CMake but I found your explanation better than all those tutorials together

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2014-09-03**:
Thank you.
I have to say that I found that part very poorly documented so I found most of that via extensive google searches. But this is not a feature of cmake but more catkin related.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-09-03**:
Wow!!! Chrissi...
Respect!

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-05-21**:
I was having the same problem but your answer wasn't enough. I had to first build only the first package `catkin_make --pkg my_package` and then run `catkin_make`. However, I have this question, does it make sense to `my_package` to depend on `my_other_package`? That seems not very good.

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2015-05-21**:
I don't get the problem. If you have to build one package first than the dependencies in the second package are not correctly defined. If you follow those instructions it should always work. You *have* to depend on packages if you use their custom messages.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-05-21**:
I have a `srv_pkg` (only with srv, no nodes) and `user_pkg` which depends on `srv_pkg`. In your first point, you do `srv_pkg` depend on `user_pkg`, but I do not understand why. However, it is clear that `user_pkg` should depend on `srv_pkg`. I have tried lots of things and couldn't make it work :(

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2015-05-21**:
In the example `my_package` would be your `user_pkg` and therefore it has to depend on `srv_pkg` if you then add the `${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}` to the `add_dependencies` and also add `srv_pkg` to the `package.xml` of the `user_pkg` it should build fine.

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2015-05-21**:
Please provide a link to the repository with your code if this still doesn't work.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-05-21**:
Thank you for your help. I was understanding it the other way around. In any case, I think I have already tried what you suggest unsuccessfully. I will try it again. :)

**Comment by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on 2016-01-21**:
Isn't `<run_depend>message_generation</run_depend>` wrong in the `package.xml`? It should be `<run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>`.

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2016-04-25**:
Correct, I'll fix it. Thanks.

**Comment by [Stian](https://answers.ros.org/users/28411/stian/) on 2017-05-18**:
Instead of `my_package_generate_messages_cpp`, one can use `${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}`. This was useful when I had to add dependencies in several packages, because I could copy_paste most of it.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-11-30**:
Great answer! A minor clarification would be that the dependency is `msg_pkg_generate_messages_cpp`, in case the message file is found in a package different from the package currently being built. Right now the answer seems to assume the build target and message are in the same package.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-18**:
What about Python ones? Is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are probably missing the line

```
add_dependencies(name_of_exe package_name_generate_messages_cpp)
```

in your CMakeLists.txt. This line should be present after target_link_libraries for the same exe.

If you have that, you will build the messages before the exe files.

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on 2016-11-22**:
For some reason THIS is always the line that gets forgotten by most users in the CMake.  Anytime, I have a build issue with messages, I always end up needing to add this line to someone's CMake file.

**Comment by [ntwong0](https://answers.ros.org/users/38580/ntwong0/) on 2018-11-16**:
Thank you! The [Creating a ROS msg and srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Common_step_for_msg_and_srv) tutorial doesn't mention this, so I really appreciate your answer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-17**:
@ntwong0: no, because the [next tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Building_your_nodes-1) explains it.